# materializecss date-picker protractor (Error: Element is not clickable at point )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, datepicker, protractor

Im trying to use date-picker similar to bithdate of(http://materializecss.com/forms.html#date-picker) and have a separate directive for it.

I tried following command

```
$('aria-owns="birthdate_root"').click();
 browser.sleep(5000);
$('data-pick="1451845800000"').click();
```

but failed and found error Element is not clickable at point

Any help is much appropriated....Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like this using [elementor](https://github.com/andresdominguez/elementor)

```
it('should select date', function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  browser.get('http://materializecss.com/forms.html#date-picker');
  $('#birthdate').click();
  $('div[aria-label="21 January, 2016"]').click();
  element(by.buttonText('Close')).click();
  expect($('#birthdate').getAttribute('value')).toBe('21 January, 2016');
});
```

Let me know if it works